# Find the files of a particular user or group

Tags: command-line, search, find, ownership, groups

How can I search the files based on the owner or group in command line?

Right now I have tried `ls -lR`, that gives all the details of files in sub directories also,  and I needed to manually search the files owned by root.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/find.1) command:

```
find /path/to/directory -user root
```

For example:

```
$ find /var -user gdm
/var/lib/gdm
/var/lib/gdm/.config
/var/lib/gdm/.config/gnome-session
/var/lib/gdm/.config/gnome-session/saved-session
/var/lib/gdm/.config/ibus
/var/lib/gdm/.config/ibus/bus
/var/lib/gdm/.config/dconf
/var/lib/gdm/.config/dconf/user
...
```